# Exception when initializing PublicKey from RSA public key stored as a string (works on laptop, not on server)

Tags: java, rsa, public-key

I have a application I am working on that deals with handling certificates and I am running into a issue where my code works correct when I run in via JUnit tests locally on my laptop but when I actually deploy the code to my server I am getting a exception.  The exception is happening while creating a PublicKey from a RSA public key stored in a String.  I am hoping someone might be able to point me in a direction to look why it fails on the server but works in the Junit.

My RSA Public Key:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAvNEz3+TStAAndHTc1qwT
NGvZYyB7DD1FshQf+mbQUGJ9HccOXNn5oHB7fWQjODjlDrYyCs7FclSMTLxA3lHX
98QWeWHL2O8t8qrJQQEUWZITmr/ddiNJOOvMeYF0K5if4m84vjgx/pTwwAVyU0Yo
MMXPnRozO8o7zSyRsH4jixALDugrsveEjLQI/cIEFvNjqlhyfumHyJKywNkMH1oJ
4e/f89FkpeDV694lsLs1jguuLLnvroXYJ5Uzeos+F0Pj1zFDUvhWrjVwxsUfAxS8
5uFGTUm6EEl9XiKwi+mgg8ODrY5dh3uE2yKB2T1Qj8BfK55zB8cYbORSsm6/f6Bi
BwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

My Junit Code: <- Works from laptop

```
@Test
public void testkey() throws Exception {
    String pem = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----"+
                "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAvNEz3+TStAAndHTc1qwT"+
                "NGvZYyB7DD1FshQf+mbQUGJ9HccOXNn5oHB7fWQjODjlDrYyCs7FclSMTLxA3lHX"+
                "98QWeWHL2O8t8qrJQQEUWZITmr/ddiNJOOvMeYF0K5if4m84vjgx/pTwwAVyU0Yo"+
        "MMXPnRozO8o7zSyRsH4jixALDugrsveEjLQI/cIEFvNjqlhyfumHyJKywNkMH1oJ"+
        "4e/f89FkpeDV694lsLs1jguuLLnvroXYJ5Uzeos+F0Pj1zFDUvhWrjVwxsUfAxS8"+
        "5uFGTUm6EEl9XiKwi+mgg8ODrY5dh3uE2yKB2T1Qj8BfK55zB8cYbORSsm6/f6Bi"+
        "BwIDAQAB"+
        "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
    PublicKey willNotWork = decodeKey(pem); 
}
```

My Actual Code: <- Throws exception when run on server

```
@Override
public PublicKey getKey() {
    PublicKey pk = null;
     try {
        String crt =  "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----"+
                "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAvNEz3+TStAAndHTc1qwT"+
                "NGvZYyB7DD1FshQf+mbQUGJ9HccOXNn5oHB7fWQjODjlDrYyCs7FclSMTLxA3lHX"+
                "98QWeWHL2O8t8qrJQQEUWZITmr/ddiNJOOvMeYF0K5if4m84vjgx/pTwwAVyU0Yo"+
                "MMXPnRozO8o7zSyRsH4jixALDugrsveEjLQI/cIEFvNjqlhyfumHyJKywNkMH1oJ"+
        "4e/f89FkpeDV694lsLs1jguuLLnvroXYJ5Uzeos+F0Pj1zFDUvhWrjVwxsUfAxS8"+
        "5uFGTUm6EEl9XiKwi+mgg8ODrY5dh3uE2yKB2T1Qj8BfK55zB8cYbORSsm6/f6Bi"+
        "BwIDAQAB"+
        "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
        System.out.append("crt == " + crt);
        pk = decodeKey(crt);
    }  catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println("getKey caught: " + ex.getMessage()); 
    }  
    return pk;
}
```

decodeKey code:

```
public PublicKey decodeKey(String text) throws CryptographyException {
    String content = text;
    if( text.contains("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----") ) {
      content = text.replace("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----", "").replace("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----", "");
    }
    if( text.contains("-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----") ) {
      content = text.replace("-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----", "").replace("-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----", "");
    }
    byte[] der = Base64.decodeBase64(content);
    return decodeDerKey(der);
}

public PublicKey decodeDerKey(byte[] publicKeyBytes) throws CryptographyException {
   try {
      KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA"); 
      PublicKey publicKey  = factory.generatePublic(
                                 new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKeyBytes)); 
      return publicKey;
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        throw new CryptographyException(e);
    }
}
```

Here's the exception that is thrown when I run my code on the server:

```
Could not parse certificate: java.io.IOException: DerInputStream.getLength():
lengthTag=111, too big`
```

So I am guessing is has to be some sort of difference between my laptop and the server.  I have verified that both are running basically the same version of Java ("1.7.0_17").  I also checked the provider of the `KeyFactory` and they are the same as well. So where do I look from here?

Comment: What happens if you run exactly the same code on both machines? It would be nice to remove any JUnit interference from the test. Also, it would help us if you can tweak your code into an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) so that we can test easier. You have undefined string constants and exceptions in your code above.

Comment: Updated the string constants. Thanks for the reference to SSCCE.  If I place the Junit function on the server and run it as normal code, I get the exception.  I am unable to run the other code locally because it is part of a web service that is deployed and so can't be debugged locally.

Comment: Issue was somewhere completely different.  Or I should say, issue was between keyboard and chair :)

Comment: Glad it's solved. If the answer would benefit others, please post it.

Comment: Issue was another piece of code that handled certs that wasn't stripping off the header and ender tags.  I had thought my code was the only one using certs so assumed it was my code messing up.  Was in a completely different part of the project.  I just was assuming it was my code and not reading the stack traces.